# How to determine a thread UI thread

Tags: winforms

what is the simple way to know which thread is UI thread or the thread which create a control in a WinForm app?

When I opened window task manager, I found 8 threads for my winform application. 
So how many of them are UI threads.

generally, how many UI threads created by the winForm engine?

Answer (score 1):

This may not answer your question since I don't know exactly what you are trying to accomplish but if [`Control.InvokeRequired`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx) is false then you are on the thread that created the control.